# Template for endianness-free code, data always packed as BIG-Endian

Tags: c++, template, bitwise

It's been a while since I've been properly grilled about my code.

I had this Idea which should probably never make it into production code but still I couldn't find anything seriously wrong with it at a glance...

All your comments are welcome.

```
#ifndef BITFIELDMEMBER_H
#define BITFIELDMEMBER_H

/************************************************************************
 * This is for creating Endianness-free bit-fields.
 * The values are always packed as big-endian.
 * When used for arithmetics/comparison, the values are read in the
 * proper endianness for the current CPU mode.
 *
 * Note: The fields can overlap if you want
 */

template<int firstBit, int bitSize>
struct BitFieldMember
{
    typedef BitFieldMember<firstBit, bitSize> self_t;
    typedef unsigned char uchar;
    enum {
        lastBit = firstBit + bitSize - 1,
        mask = (1 << bitSize) - 1
    };
    uchar *selfArray()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<uchar *>(this);
    }
    const uchar *selfArray() const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<const uchar *>(this);
    }

    /* used to read data from the field */
    /* will also work with all the operators that work with integral types */
    inline operator unsigned() const
    {
        const uchar *arr = selfArray();
        const uchar *p = arr + firstBit / 8;
        int i = 8 - (firstBit & 7);
        unsigned ret = 0;
        ret |= *p;
        while (i < bitSize)
        {
            ret <<= 8;
            ret |= *(++p);
            i += 8;
        }
        return ((ret >> (7 - (lastBit & 7))) & mask);
    }

    /* used to assign a value into the field */
    inline self_t& operator=(unsigned m)
    {
        uchar *arr = selfArray();
        m &= mask;
        unsigned wmask = ~(mask << (7 - (lastBit & 7)));
        m <<= (7 - (lastBit & 7));
        uchar *p = arr + lastBit / 8;
        int i = (lastBit & 7) + 1;
        (*p &= wmask) |= m;
        while (i < bitSize)
        {
            m >>= 8;
            wmask >>= 8;
            (*(--p) &= wmask) |= m;
            i += 8;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    inline self_t& operator+=(unsigned m)
    {
        *this = *this + m;
        return *this;
    }

    inline self_t& operator-=(unsigned m)
    {
        *this = *this - m;
        return *this;
    }

    inline self_t& operator*=(unsigned m)
    {
        *this = *this * m;
        return *this;
    }

    inline self_t& operator/=(unsigned m)
    {
        *this = *this / m;
        return *this;
    }

    inline self_t& operator%=(unsigned m)
    {
        *this = *this % m;
        return *this;
    }

    inline self_t& operator<<=(unsigned m)
    {
        *this = *this << m;
        return *this;
    }

    inline self_t& operator>>=(unsigned m)
    {
        *this = *this >> m;
        return *this;
    }

    inline self_t& operator|=(unsigned m)
    {
        *this = *this | m;
        return *this;
    }

    inline self_t& operator&=(unsigned m)
    {
        *this = *this & m;
        return *this;
    }

    inline self_t& operator^=(unsigned m)
    {
        *this = *this ^ m;
        return *this;
    }

};
#endif
```

Usage example:

```
union header
{
    unsigned char arr[2];       // space allocation, 2 bytes (16 bits)

    BitFieldMember<0, 4> m1;     // first 4 bits
    BitFieldMember<4, 5> m2;     // The following 5 bits
    BitFieldMember<9, 6> m3;     // The following 6 bits, total 16 bits
};

int main()
{
    header a;
    memset(a.arr, 0, sizeof(a.arr));
    a.m1 = rand();
    a.m3 = a.m1;
    a.m2 = ~a.m1;
    return 0;
}
```

This sometimes wouldn't work for fields that are larger than 24 bits... the shifting may trim the most significant bits.

Comment: there's a blog post with the same code here http://blog.codef00.com/2014/12/06/portable-bitfields-using-c11/. Is this yours? It mentions UB, but does not specify where and what kind of UB that is. Could you probably tell more about that?

Comment: That one isn't me. I didn't read the blog post. What is UB?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour. Funny, that blog post appeared at about the same time as yours, and the code is similar, though a bit different.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you guys, I was having issues with my C++ implementation of bitfields and this is a life saver.

Comment: Thanks @Teslik, thrilled to know that it's still relevant so many years later. I've been enjoying using it too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is good, except for two methods : `operator unsigned() const` and `self_t& operator=(unsigned m)`. They are too complex, and by just looking at them, it is far from clear what they are doing.

First, you can add new values to your enum :

```
enum {
    lastBit = firstBit + bitSize - 1,
    mask = (1 << bitSize) - 1,
    firstBitIndex = 8 - (firstBit & 7),                         // change to proper name
    nameThisValueProperly = (7 - (lastBit & 7)) & mask,         // change to proper name
};
```

First modify your `operator unsigned() const` to this :

```
inline operator unsigned() const
{
    const uchar *arr = selfArray();
    const uchar *p = arr + firstBit / 8;

    unsigned result = CalculateSomeValue( p );

    return (result >> nameThisValueProperly );
}

// name this method properly
inline unsigned CalculateSomeValue( const uchar *p ) const
{
    int i = firstBitIndex;
    unsigned result = *p;

    while (i < bitSize)
    {
        result <<= 8;
        result |= *(++p);
        i += 8;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Of course, you need to put proper names both for enum values and method names, so when someone looks into this code says "Aha, that is what is is doing". This way, you can easy increase code clarity.

Also, by making method smaller, you can easily test them.

More about this method, you can read in [Clean code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882) by Robert Martin.

You can do something similar for the `self_t& operator=(unsigned m)`. Break it up, until you find it clean.

Comment: There's a small bug in there: `nameThisValueProperly = (7 - (lastBit & 7)) & mask` breaks things for field sizes 1 & 2.  Removing **&mask** fixes it, but make sure there's a **&mask** wherever this value gets used.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few things found wrong with this implementation when using it in production code are the following:

Assignment between fields that are of the exact same type will result in an empty implementation **with nothing copied** because the fields have no storage of their own.
To resolve this, it's best to cast the right side of the assignment to `unsigned`. The trouble is finding this bug in the first place.

A workaround would have been to block the assignment by either making it `private` or delete it with `= delete` and let the compiler find it for you but this will require C++11 or higher.

C++03 doesn't allow union members to be types that have declarations for assignment operators.

Also, it's missing some operators:

```
inline self_t& operator++()
{
    *this = *this + 1;
    return *this;
}

inline self_t& operator--()
{
    *this = *this - 1;
    return *this;
}

inline unsigned operator++(int)
{
    unsigned tmp = *this;
    *this = tmp + 1;
    return tmp;
}

inline unsigned operator--(int)
{
    unsigned tmp = *this;
    *this = tmp - 1;
    return tmp;
}
```

Last and least (assuming `unsigned` is 32 bits), if someone insists on having fields that are 32 bits, you will need to make the following modification to the enum of the mask:

```
enum
{
    lastBit = firstBit + bitSize - 1,
    mask = (1ULL << bitSize) - 1
};
```

Other than that, it served us well.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, assignment between objects of the union type works fine because it's basically just a `memcpy`

Answer (score 2):

I implemented yours with the following changes:

- Replaced `enum` with `static constexpr`
- Deleted default / copy / move constructors

  - Constructors imply ownership of resources.  I figured this would help avoid undefined behavior
- Deleted unary `operator&()` for similar reasons.
- Implemented `self_t& operator=(const self_t&)` to deal with the problem you noted:

  > Assignment between fields that are of the exact same type will result in an empty implementation **with nothing copied** because the fields have no storage of their own.

  Originally I added an array, necessitating an extra template argument: `BitfieldMember<sizeof(data), ...>`, but this made it unnecessary.
- Added the template argument from the last bullet and a static_assert in an attempt to require the storage be large enough.
- Changed the set/get logic for readability:

---

```
private:
inline operator base_type() const {
  base_type ret = 0;
  for( unsigned ii = firstBit / 8; ii <= lastBit / 8; ++ii ) {
    ret = (ret << 8) | data()[ii];
  }
  return (ret >> excessBitsInLastByte) & mask;
}
inline self_t& operator=( base_type m ) {
  m = (m & mask) << excessBitsInLastByte;
  base_type write_mask = mask << excessBitsInLastByte;
  for( int ii = lastBit / 8; ii >= 0 && 0 != write_mask; --ii ) {
    uchar& ref = data()[ii];
    ref &= ~write_mask;
    ref |= m;
    m >>= 8;
    write_mask >>= 8;
  }
  return *this;
}
```

---

I've been looking for a way to add compile time errors for the following situations but haven't managed it yet:

- if any fields overlap

  - I have some ideas for this, haven't tried them yet.
- if the union's size is larger than its array

  - This works but I was hoping for something more automatic: put a static_assert after the union definition is complete.
- if virtual functions are added to BitfieldMember (or derived classes have virtual functions)

  - The vtable will increase the union's size and each one will clobber each-other's vtable.
  - It's probably not possible to catch the latter case
- If data members are added to BitfieldMember (or deriving classes)

  - I can catch the first case automatically, but I don't think it's possible to catch the 2nd case.